# converting from vector<derived>::iterator to vector<base>::iterator

Tags: c++, stl, iterator, polymorphism

Is it possible to do the operation described in the title? Here is a concrete example of what I want to do:

```
#include <vector>
class Base{
public:
    Base(int t){tst = t;}
protected:
    int tst;
};

class Derived : public Base{
public:
    Derived(int t):Base(t){} 
};

int main(){
    std::vector<Derived> test;
    test.push_back(Derived(1));
    std::vector<Base>::iterator iTest = test.begin();
}
```

The last line fails. using static_cast doesn't work either. Is there a good way to do this? How could I iterate over a vector of derived class objects as a vector of base class objects otherwise?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can not convert them together.

I think you need something like this:

```
std::vector<Base*> test;
test.push_back( new Derived(1) );

std::vector<Base*>::iterator iTest = test.begin();

// ....

// cleanup
```

And then enjoy the polymorphism advantages.

Comment: THAT is where my great oversight was. I had thought to do that in a different context for this problem, but not this current one. Thanks!

Comment: Note if you're using C++11, this same iteration can be written (with polymorphism) like this:
 ***for(Base &base : vectorOfDerived)***  (if you are iterating from begin() to end() without moving or adding elements)

Answer (score 2):

Nope, the types are unrelated.

If you want to expose a sequence of `Base` objects, hiding the fact that they're actually `Derived`, you could do it with [`boost::iterator_adaptor`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/iterator/doc/iterator_adaptor.html).  The resulting type is not `vector<Base>::iterator`, but it is an iterator that gives a `Base` when dereferenced.

```
#include <boost/iterator/iterator_adaptor.hpp>

class BaseIter
    : public boost::iterator_adaptor<
         BaseIter,                         // This class type for CRTP
         std::vector<Derived>::iterator,   // Underlying iterator type
         Base >                            // Desired value_type
{
public:
    BaseIter()
      : iterator_adaptor() {}
    explicit BaseIter( std::vector<Derived>::iterator iter )
      : iterator_adaptor(iter) {}
};
```

(You might want `const Base` rather than `Base` as the `value_type`.)